# Using rmd in shiny or put the shiny into rmd, which is more efficient in omics data analysis

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, bioinformatics

I am in the process of creating an app for processing and visualizing plots of omics data (mainly lipidomics and metabolomics).
I'm quite a beginner, I only started learning R 6 months ago, and it's possible that this app will only spread in my lab, but I personally would really like it to benchmark against [MetaboAnalyst](https://www.metaboanalyst.ca/).
:) You can check out my newborn baby app [here](https://toxin.shinyapps.io/612hub)
Recently, I am looking for solutions in order to trace the processing and good reproducibility.
I've learned of two ways to do this.

1. We can generate an RMD report in shiny by adding a download button to tell the user what they actually did with the data, but I'm guessing there might be a lot to write in `downloadHandler(filename, content)`?
2. Or make an RMD template, divide it into different sections, put shiny controls, and just save it at the end.

I'd like to know which way is the better solution, for the sake of non-R user friendliness and to make research more reliable.